# Math random add subtract counter limited between a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, counter

can you help me out on how to limit the below to stay within a min and max range eg 3 - 10

```
<div id="number">3</div> 

  setInterval(function(){
    random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*1)+1));
    var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    random = random * plusOrMinus; 
    currentnumber = document.getElementById('number');

    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML) + random;

 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Mozilla Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values

> **Getting a random integer between two values** This example returns a random integer between the specified values. The value is no lower
> than min (or the next integer greater than min if min isn't an
> integer), and is less than (but not equal to) max.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

By Mozilla Contributors, licensed under CC-BY-SA 2.5.